# FullCalendar Angular Switch View

Tags: angular, fullcalendar

Using fullcalendar.io api There is a demo that allows you to click a date in GridView (of the month)
That changes the view to see the day by the hour
Where is there an angular example  Or how is this done.

Also can you limit the hours shown to just 8am to 5pm?

Thanks

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-nav-links

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/slotMinTime, https://fullcalendar.io/docs/slotMaxTime

Comment: For Angular, the options are identical, only the syntax to set them is slightly different - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/angular. Everything you've asked about in your question is already in the documentation. And note also that the demos in the documentation contain links to their source code so you can see exactly how each one was built.